# Extract values from column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

How to extract the following values from a column in SQL Server:

```
"ICMP (type: 8 / subtype: 0)" -----> "8" and "0"
"ICMP (type: 0 / subtype: 19)" -----> "0" and "19"
"ICMP (type: 11 / subtype: 5)" -----> "11" and "5"
"ICMP (type: 12 / subtype: 30)" -----> "12" and "30"
```

I tried different functions - charindex(), left(), right() but I failed.

Comment: The failure is storing multiple pieces of data in a single field. This violates the most fundamental design rule and needs fixing. Parse the data before you enter it into the database instead. It's a **lot** easier to parse data in eg C# using a regular expression or a purpose-made parser than performing even simple string manipulation in T-SQL

Comment: Querying that data can't use any indexes, so every time you want to read those values you'd have to scan and parse the entire table. Parsing that field would make sense only if you wanted to move to a better schema and wanted to migrate old data. In every other case, it's faster to use another language to parse the strings. Even R or Python in SQL Server 2016 and later.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server is not great at string manipulation.  But `cross apply` helps a bit:

```
select left(v.str1, charindex(' ', v.str1)) as type, replace(v.str2, ')', '') as subtype
from (values ('ICMP (type: 8 / subtype: 0)'), ('ICMP (type: 12 / subtype: 30)')) t(field) cross apply
     (values ( stuff(field, 1, charindex('type:', field) + 5, ''),
               stuff(field, 1, charindex('subtype:', field) + 8, '')
             )
     ) v(str1, str2);
```

Comment: I'd say that using SQL Server's R or Python scripts and a regex would be easier and faster, but [the required boilerplate](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6459/sql-server-regex-capabilities-using-python/) could be almost as confusing to a new user

Comment: This is hideously elegant.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos . . . I would imagine that the overhead of running Python or R would be vastly greater than the overhead of SQL Server's built-in string functions.  If you know differently, I would be interested in learning.